# Tesseract.exe path on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, python, tesseract-ocr

I want to use pytesseract on Ubuntu computer with Python. On Windows computer I had to set path to tesseract.exe before I call 
image to string function. How can I set this path on ubuntu computer?I cannot find path to tesseract.exe on my computer.
Same question for the variable tesseract-PREFIX for data.
Thanks in advance.
Marek

Answer (score 1):

To set a directory as part of the path in Ubuntu, you would need to edit the `$PATH` environment variable in `bash`. You can do this in two ways: one is permanent, one is for the duration of a `bash` session.

The temporary way: set it using the `export` command. You can do this by running this command in your session:

```
export PATH=$PATH:{directory of tesseract binary}
```

(Without the curly brackets, of course)

The permanent way: adding it to your .bashrc file. You can do this by running `nano .bashrc` and adding the command from above to the bottom of the text file. Then, start a new session, and every time your tesseract program's directory will be in the path.

Comment: Thanks, but I can‘t find tesseract.exe on Ubuntu system. On Windows I found tesseract.exe and I set the Path.

Comment: Ubuntu does not run .exe files, it just runs binaries if they are marked as executable in their permissions. Try using the command `find tesseract` or `find pytesseract` and it will give you a directory where your binary is.